# How to make Erase operations asynchronous for Coherence Write-Behind configuration?

Tags: caching, oracle-coherence

I just noticed that **delete from persistence storage** ([com.tangosol.net.cache.CacheStore#erase](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/coherence/340/com/tangosol/net/cache/CacheStore.html#erase(java.lang.Object))) operations could not be postponed with the [Oracle Coherence Write-Behind](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14447_01/coh.330/coh33ug/readthroughwritethrough.htm) configuration, only inserts and updates could be asynchronous here.

Could anybody please advise if **deletion** also could be write-behind-ed here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems, there is no way to get delete / remove operations asynchronous for Write-Behind:

> In the Write-Behind scenario, modified cache entries are asynchronously written to the data source after a configured delay, whether after 10 seconds, 20 minutes, a day, a week or even longer. Note that this only applies to cache inserts and updates - **cache entries are removed synchronously from the data source.**